# Isolating barium(II), copper(II) and zinc(II) from aqueous solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, transition-metals, reduction-potential

> **Q15** Each metallic ion was separated from an aqueous solution containing $\ce{Ba^2+},$ $\ce{Cu^2+},$ and $\ce{Zn^2+}$ by the procedure shown in the following figure. From ①–⑥ in the table below choose the correct combination of ions that predominates in the precipitates **a**, **b** and the filtrate **c**.
>
> [image]

For the precipitate **a**, I know the answer is $\ce{Ba^2+}$ ion because it has a highly negative standard reduction potential than the other ions, so it tends to displace the sulfuric acid to form insoluble barium sulfate.

But I don't know which one can displace $\ce{NaOH}.$ $\ce{Na+}$ ion reduction potential is a lot more negative than both $\ce{Cu^2+}$ and $\ce{Zn^2+}$ ions. I suspect there is something in 'added in excess' part, but I don't know how can it be any different.

Comment: Reduction potential is quite irrelevant here. You might want to review what do you know about the amphoteric properties of Zn.

Comment: $\ce{NaOH}$ is added in excess to first neutralize the sulfuric acid from the first step and then to make the pH go up beyond 7.

Comment: @AegisNine I suggest you look up the properties of Zn(OH)4 dianion

Comment: So, this related to properties of transition metal, and not reduction potential, but Ba is not d-block metal, how can I compare it? This is an undergrad admission exam, so is it really necessary to know the specific properties of a compound?

Comment: The answer is a=Ba, b=Cu, c=Zn from answer key, but from searching a lot it looks like both Cu and Zn can reach with NaOH, Zn with its amphoteric properties, Cu by firstly forming oxides(?)

Comment: Of course both Cu and Zn will react with NaOH. But they will react in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once $\ce{Ba^2+}$ is eliminated as poorly soluble barium(II) sulfate, there is a solution of soluble copper(II) and zinc(II) sulfates.
Considering this has been done by careful/gradual addition of sulfuric acid, and the fact that both remaining sulfates undergo hydrolysis, the solution is going to be slightly acidic — this is one reason for sodium hydroxide "*added in excess*".

Another reason, as both Ivan and Waylander pointed out in the comments, is the difference between reactivity of copper(II) and zinc(II) in alkali medium.
Long story short, you are probably *supposed to know* the specific properties of the common transition metals cations as the reduction potential isn't really helpful here.

#### Copper(II)

Copper(II) with $\ce{NaOH}$ first forms colloidal copper(II) hydroxide; the gel is then solidifies to light-blue amorphous substance upon subsequent addition of hydroxide:

$$\ce{CuSO4(aq) + 2 NaOH(aq) -> Cu(OH)2(s) + Na2SO4(aq)}$$

$\ce{Cu(OH)2(s)}$ appears to be precipitate **b**.
Sodium tetrahydroxocuprate(II) $\ce{Na2[Cu(OH)4]}$ **doesn't form here**: it's a very moisture-sensitive and in the air quickly turns dark-brown:

$$\ce{Na2[Cu(OH)4](aq) -> CuO(s) + H2O(l) + 2 Na(OH)(aq)}$$

#### Zinc(II)

Zinc(II), on the other hand, with $\ce{NaOH}$ first forms white precipitate of zinc(II) hydroxide:

$$\ce{\ce{ZnSO4(aq) + 2 NaOH(aq) -> Zn(OH)2(s) + Na2SO4(aq)}}$$

which is then dissolved again forming colorless soluble sodium terahydroxozincate(II) (filtrate **c**):

$$\ce{Zn(OH)2(s) + 2 NaOH(aq) -> Na2[Zn(OH)4](aq)}$$

Excess of $\ce{NaOH}$ is also necessary to keep $\ce{Na2[Zn(OH)4]}$ in solution: upon diluting (lowering pH, adding water/acid), terahydroxozincate(II) decomposes to zinc(II) hydroxide.

Note: chemical reactions are adapted from [1].

#### References

1. R. A. Lidin, V. A. Molochko, and L. L. Andreeva, *Reactivity of Inorganic Substances*, 3rd ed.; Khimia: Moscow, **2000**. (in Russian)